# can you use one time password to encrypt communication between mobile and server?

Tags: one-time-password

If SSL is not acceptable for my app to communicate with the client, how should I encrypt the traffic? I need something fast (so public key algorithms are out of question).
I was thinking about One Time Password, but the problem is that I can not store a very long key on the mobile app because of app size restrictions. What would you recommend?

Comment: Public key algorithms are only used by SSL to set up a session. Once a session is set up, no public key operations are needed. The bulk encryption is done by symmetric algorithms that are plenty fast. Use SSL. (Are you confusing a one time *password* with a one time *pad*? Passwords don't have to be particularly long, whether one time or not.)

Comment: @David: The *"I can not store a very long key on the mobile"* suggests you are right, he means One Time Pad.

Comment: Your question is possibly better suited for http://security.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How do you know that SSL isn't acceptably fast? Have you benchmarked it? As David said, SSL only uses public-key cryptography for the setup and to establish a shared secret, which is then used as the key to quick symmetric algorithms. So before you reject SSL, you should actually test it first.